# Setup Matomo on DO droplet behind Cloudflare to serve a GhostCMS website

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, cloudflare, matomo

I am trying to access the browser Matomo installer.  I can only get a 404.  Also, if I try to setup a GoAccess in browser report, I have the same issue.

I have followed this https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-nginx.
I have not specifically setup Cloudflare.
Matomo folder resides under /var/www

in the matomo.conf file:

```
root /var/www/matomo

server_name www.blabla.com blabla.com;
```

I cant't see where is the issue.  How can I access the matomo folder and initiated the configuration script.

Comment: check the nginx log and make sure `/var/www/matomo` is really the path to the index.php (and the matomo.conf is read)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am moving to a stand alone server and will redo from scratch the nginx config.